# how to isolate the content in Div

Tags: css, html

as we know, the content of a fixed-size div will go out of the div, in case they need more space.
ex : http://jsfiddle.net/YaTeG/
now my question is how to stop it without any js ? i mean like an iframe ! which has scrollbars if we need more space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you update your css like this;

```
#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px; height: 200px;
    top: 20px; left: 20px;
    background-color: #ff0;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

it will autoscroll authomaticallywhen your content is bigger than div.

```
overflow:auto;
```

You can have look at [here](http://css-tricks.com/examples/OverflowExample/) for different style of this case

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`overflow`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html) property.

- `overflow: hidden` if you want it to be cut, or
- `overflow: auto` if you want scrollbars to appear in case the content is too long.

Answer (score 1):

`overflow` property controls both scrollbars horizontal and vertical. If you want further control, you can set the `overflow` property separately for each scrollbar.

`overflow-x` property controls the horizontal scrollbar and `overflow-y` - for the vertical

e.g.

```
.some_element{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```